# Read xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml

i need to parse it to get elements in php i just use simple xml file, but is it possible via c#

```
    <answers>
<answer ID="START">
<text>VVLV?</text>
<id>0</id>
<responses>

<response id="1">
<key>!1</key>
<product> 123123 </product>
<command>goto ANSWER_1</command>
</response>

<response id="2">
<key>!2</key>
<product> 213sad </product>
<command>goto ANSWER_2</command>
</response>

<response id="3">
<key>!3</key>
<product>dfbdfgsdf </product>
<command>goto ANSWER_3</command>

</response>

</responses>

</answer>

<answer ID="ANSWER_1">
<text>dfbdfgb?</text>
<id>1</id>
<responses>

<response id="1">
<key>!1</key>
<product> 123 </product>
<command>check_product 1 goto ANSWER_9 ANSWER_11</command>
</response>

<response id="2">
<key>!2</key>
<product> 321 </product>
<command>check_product 1 goto ANSWER_9 ANSWER_12</command>
</response>

<response id="3">
<key>!3</key>
<product> asd 3 </product>
<command>check_product 1 goto ANSWER_9 ANSWER_11</command>

</response>

</responses>

</answer>


<answer ID="ANSWER_2">
<text>asd?</text>
<id>2</id>
<responses>

<response id="1">
<key>!1</key>
<product> ads </product>
<command>goto ANSWER_4</command>
</response>

<response id="2">
<key>!2</key>
<product> asdasd </product>
<command>goto ANSWРІER_2</command>
</response>

<response id="3">
<key>!3</key>
<product> dscdsc</product>
<command>goto ANSWER_3</command>

</response>

</responses>

</answer>

<answer ID="ANSWER_3">
<text>asdasd</text>
<password>1</password>
<id>3</id>
<responses>

<response id="1">
<key>!1</key>
<product> asdasd </product>
<command>goto ANSWER_0</command>
</response>

<response id="2">
<key>!2</key>
<product>  </product>
<command>goto ANSWER_2</command>
</response>

<response id="3">
<key>!3</key>
<product> Testqdawd 3 </product>
<command>goto ANSWER_3</command>

</response>

</responses>

</answer>
```

How i can parse it in C# for example how i can get valuse of elent in answer with ID="START"->responses->response with id 3->key

Comment: How about RTFM? There is plenty of stuff on MSDN.

Comment: Read on up [LINQ To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Comment: The community here doesn't like questions that show lack of research and/or effort. This question shows such a lack.

Comment: Question has a very broad scope. There are many ways to do it in c#. one way would be to create a data model in c# with xml attributes and deserialize your xml using XmlSerializer to the instance of that class and deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). And you definitely should have done that before asking any question here!

Using `XDocument.Load` method you can easily load your XML into `XDocument` object:

```
var dox = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");
```

And then query it using standard LINQ to XML syntax:

```
var response = (from a in dox.Root.Elements("answer")
                where (string)a.Attribute("ID") == "ANSWER_1"
                from r in a.Element("responses").Elements("response")
                where (int)r.Attribute("id") == 1
                select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or XPath selector:

```
var response = dox.XPathSelectElement("answers/answer[@ID='ANSWER_1']/responses/response[@id='1']");
```